# Running Microsoft Teams in Minimal X-Window System

Tags: debian, x11, microsoft-teams

My system is set up as follows:
Linux Distro = Debian (minimal install with standard utilities and the following:)
xorg
ratpoison
fvwm

I installed Microsoft Teams for Linux using the supplied deb package at https://teams.microsoft.com/uswe-01/downloads

Running teams from an xterm in xorg, the process will run and be seen by 'ps', but the teams window never pops or shows.

What widget is Teams using or how can I find out?

I've ran it no problems in Fedora 33 Workstation, so some dependency is missing. I've tried manually installing gtk and motif. Both don't seem to work.

Comment: MS Teams is an Electron app, essentially running a javascript app inside Chromium (Google's Chrome). You could check Chromium's or Chrome dependencies or install one of them; it might help.

Answer (score 0):

As Krackout suggested in the comments above, I installed the **chromium** package using **apt**. Now Teams launches correctly.